# Reputation reversed from my account

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting

Today I found that my 145 reputation deducted from my account so can any one help about this?

Comment: It was detected as serial upvoting. There is nothing you can do.

Comment: Check your inbox. You were contacted by a moderator about this yesterday.

Answer (score 17):

This was a reversal of what was determined to be votes specifically targeted at you. 16 votes that you received from a single user were invalidated. I can't give the specifics of precisely *what* is considered, but the pattern looked basically identical to someone using multiple accounts to artificially inflate their reputation.

You didn't do anything *wrong* unless you encouraged a friend or co worker to go up vote all of your posts, many in rapid succession, some so quickly that they couldn't have *possibly* been read prior to voting.

There's nothing that can be done about this. If you have friends that use Stack Overflow, it's absolutely fine if they up vote you occasionally, but those votes need to be anchored in the technical merit of the posts they're voting for. Abnormal patterns are quickly detected and quite often reversed, this is needed to keep the reputation system fair. If these had been down votes, they would have been reversed in the same manner.

Answer (score 4):

You have a *Serial upvoting reversed* entry in your reputation history. That means *someone* voted many of your posts up and that got corrected.

This is considered a voting irregularity. It is not appropriate to just upvote posts from someone. Voting should not be connected to the person that posted, but to the content itself.

The system detects such serial votes and reverses them automatically once a day.

Comment: Its worth noting that this doesn't (nessissarily) mean you've done anything wrong. Its the serial upvoter who's in the wrong, and their votes that have been invalidated

Answer (score 4):

Your [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2423840/manish-sharma?tab=reputation) mentions that the system has detected [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me), so the reps you got from those votes have been removed automatically. Screenshot given below:

[image]